# cursor not adding data, adding only when executing separately

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I have stored procedure & cursor loop which I am using to add  data in main table issue is I am adding data from csv file to temp table and from temp table to main table

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateHub]
  @HubName varchar(100)
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.HUB1
                         (HUB_NAME)
SELECT        @HubName
WHERE        (NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT        ID_HUB, HUB_NAME
                               FROM            dbo.HUB1
                               WHERE        (HUB1.hub_name = @HubName)))

SELECT        ID_HUB AS newHubId
FROM            dbo.HUB1
WHERE        (hub1.hub_name = @HubName)

GO
```

Once this is done, there is another code which is doing bulk insert from csv file and running cursor loop for adding data in main table

```
bulk insert [dbo].[HUB_temp]
from 'C:\POPAD-DAT\HUB1.csv'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go

DECLARE @sSQL AS nVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ItemsFromCSV  AS nvarchar(200)

DECLARE sql_cursor_hub CURSOR
    FOR SELECT HUB_NAME FROM HUB_temp
OPEN sql_cursor_hub

FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor_hub 
INTO @ItemsFromCSV  -- Multiple variables for multiple CSV columns will be required

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @sSQL = 'EXEC  [dbo].[CreateHub] ' + @ItemsFromCSV  -- AND OTHER Parameters
print @sSQl
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL

FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor_hub
END 

CLOSE sql_cursor_hub;

DEALLOCATE sql_cursor_hub;
```

Running cursor is not adding data its showing like same id and showing different u=hubname but not inserting data

While if I am running separately executing SP it is adding like this

```
EXEC  [dbo].[CreateHub] 'SGGSP30'
EXEC  [dbo].[CreateHub] 'USGSP20'
```

can you please help where exactly iam going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to do INTO in the second fetch

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  set @sSQL = 'EXEC  [dbo].[CreateHub] ' + @ItemsFromCSV  -- AND OTHER Parameters
  print @sSQl
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL

  -- This is changed
  FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor_hub INTO @ItemsFromCSV
END
```

You should also take care of your parameter declarations, `@ItemsFromCSV` is varchar(200) but the stored proc parameter is only varchar(100) and `@sSQL` is only 100 in size but you add `@ItemsFromCSV` to it.